# How to get audio metadata from its path in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-channel

I have path of the audio file like "sdcard://music/ABC.mp3" . How to get other details  such as album, artist, duration etc from that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound), there are utility methods which can give you the duration in milliseconds and some other metadata. From the package docs:

```
int duration = await flutterSoundHelper.duration( this._path[_codec.index] );
Map<dynamic, dynamic> info = await flutterSoundHelper.FFmpegGetMediaInformation( uri );
```

Comment: requires api 21

Comment: What are _path and _codec?

Comment: If you read the docs of the package it should give you an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fluter_music_player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flute_music_player) plugin to play, pause, album artist, duration etc. It's support both ios and android.

See [Flutter Music Player](https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-Music-Player) this sample Music player flutter project using this plugin

Comment: The project itself says 'This project is not implemented for ios yet.So wait for it or if you can contribute then please do help.'  Careful when trying for IOS.